# css - clear floats doesn't work

Tags: css, css-float

I have a clear floats problem I can't figure out. This is the HTML code:

```
 <div id="main">
   <div id="primary">
      <div id="content" role="main">
      </div><!-- #content -->
   </div><!-- #primary -->
   <div id="secondary">
   <div><!-- #secondary -->
 </div><!-- #main -->
```

This is the CSS for each element:

```
#main {
clear: both;
}

#primary {
float: left;
width: 100%;
margin: 0 -40% 0 0!important;
}

#content {
background: none repeat scroll 0 0 white;
box-shadow: 0px 10px 10px 2px #888;
float: left;
margin: 0 12.3%!important;
position: relative;
width: auto;
 }

#secondary {
float: right;
margin-right: 15%;
width: 22%;
position: relative;
padding-top: 170px;
}
```

The website is build on wordpress so `main` starts in header.php and ends in footer.php. The `primary` and `content` divs start and end in each page template and the `secondary` div is called in each page template (get sidebar) after the `primary` div ends.

The problem is that the content div stops right after the primary div ends, while the secondary div goes on extending below. The content div should extend until the end of the document where the secondary or main div ends.

You can view the code live and the problem it's causing on this [website](http://nelsonandco.pro/learncenter/about/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is that the 'secondary' element isn't contained within the 'content' element' on your site so obviously 'content' won't grow to accomodate 'secondary'.

You need to have a rethink of your html structure.

Comment: Yes, that was indeed the problem. I've included the 'secondary' div into the 'primary' and 'content'. Now I've finished fixing all the problems that resulted from this move and everything works ok. Thanks!

Comment: @GeorgeGrigorita - Glad to be of help :)

Comment: I agree with @Billy Moat. The [float property](https://kolosek.com/css-float/) specifies how the element will be placed to the left or right of the parent container. So you need to **put both of the floated elements inside of the container**.

Answer (score 1):

Its because of `float`

give `overflow property` to your parent.

or create an extra div and give `clear:both`

One of the common problems we face when coding with float based layouts is that the wrapper container doesn't expand to the height of the child floating elements.The typical solution to fix this is by adding an element with `clear float` after the floating elements or adding a `clearfix` to the wrapper. But you can also use the overflow property to fix this problem. It's not a new CSS trick either. It's been documented before long long ago.

Answer (score 0):

Parent elements are never to expand to contain floated elements. To have that element expand to contain them, you add `overflow: auto` to the parent so the floated element overflowing the element will be contained in most cases. I was unable to find an element to apply that to so you may have done other things to cause this. position:absolute has the same issue where it is taken out of the normal flow and parent elements will not contain them.

Answer (score 0):

The `clear` property in css needs to be applied to a new `div` in your code. It works by starting the div below all floating elements within the parent element. It would look something like this:

```
<div id="main">
  <div id="primary">
    <div id="content" role="main">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="secondary">
  <div>
  <div style="clear: both"></div> <!-- Don't do inline styles -->
</div>
```

That should do it. You also should take out the `clear: both` on `#main's` CSS. It's not necessary.